# R: how to order a data frame according to a column AND to a external variable in one command

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to order a data frame first according to one column in an ascending manner, and to a second column specified by the levels in an external variable.

Given the following MWE:

```
mylevels <- c("domain", "kingdom", "phylum", "class", "order", "family", "genus", "species")
mydf <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("A","B","C"), each=8), LEVEL=rep(mylevels, 3), VALUE=1:24)
mydf2 <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf)),]
```

I want to order mydf2 to obtain the original order in mydf, according to ID ascendantly, and to LEVEL as specified in mylevels, in one command. Is it possible?

(note mydf is kept for demonstration purposes, in my real life case I start from mydf2)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set factor levels on `LEVEL` with the correct order, then sort by ID and LEVEL:

```
mydf2$LEVEL = factor(mydf2$LEVEL, levels = mylevels)
mydf2 = mydf2[order(mydf2$ID, mydf2$LEVEL), ]
```

Output:

```
> head(mydf2)
  ID   LEVEL VALUE
1  A  domain     1
2  A kingdom     2
3  A  phylum     3
4  A   class     4
5  A   order     5
6  A  family     6
```